# Why does filtering on the tags page remove the descriptions from the tags?

Tags: support, bug, tags, filtering

I noticed today that when you filter on the tags page for any SE site, the description of the tags get removed:

[image: tag filter]

Is there a reason that the descriptions get removed? I'd find it more helpful if they were to remain after you apply a filter.  I did think it could be because of backend filtering and to cut down on response size/time, but it appears to be making the same request to `filter/tags-for-index` whether you apply a filter or not.